# Regex to match word beginning with @

Tags: c#, .net, regex, vb.net

I am trying to develop some regex to find all words that start with an @:

I thought that `\@\w+` would do it but this also matches words that have @ contained within them

e.g.
`@help me@ ple@se @now`

matches at `Index: 0 Length 5, Index: 13 Length 3, Index: 17 Length 4`

This shouldn't match at Index 13 should it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `\B@\w+` (non-word boundary).

For example:

```
string pattern = @"\B@\w+";
foreach (var match in Regex.Matches(@"@help me@ ple@se @now", pattern))
    Console.WriteLine(match);
```

output:

```
@help
@now
```

BTW, you don't need to escape `@`.

http://ideone.com/nsT015

Comment: Ahhh, great answer +1. Eliminated the look behind.

Comment: On the irony of "you don't need to escape @" your test string didn't need the `@` before it either. It would make no difference. :)

Comment: It took me a second to figure out how non-word boundary would work here; nicely played

Answer (score 4):

How about a negative look-behind:

```
(?<!\w)@\w+
```

Comment: Thanks Marc that only picks up the ple@se however

Comment: @MattWilko added a "start of line" ;p

Comment: That now picks up `Index: 0 Length 5, Index: 13 Length 3`

Comment: @MattWilko 3rd time lucky?

Comment: Yes thanks +1 but I am going to accept @falsetru 's answer for its simplicity

Comment: Won't work in JS running on Safari.

Answer (score 1):

And what about a non-Regex approach?

C# version:

```
string input = "word1 word2 @word3 ";
string[] resultWords = input.Split(' ').ToList().Where(x => x.Trim().StartsWith("@")).ToArray();
```

VB.NET version:

```
Dim input As String = "word1 word2 @word3 "
Dim resultWords() As String = input.Split(" "c).ToList().Where(Function(x) x.Trim().StartsWith("@")).ToArray
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
(?<=^|\s)@\w+
```

Can't remember if c# allows alternation in a look behind

[RegExr](http://regexr.com?37e2v)

Comment: Yes it does, and yes that works; the negative look-behind may be (subjectively) simpler, but: that works

Comment: Ah tbf, I wouldn't have posted if I'd noticed your updated answer.